# How to test database performance

Tags: database, performance

If searching is too slow when traffic is high, how would I be able to test the impact of changes on a database without changing anything.

Lets say I believed we should change clustered index. It could turn out good or bad. How do I test it without risking business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup of your current production database. Move that copy to your test/staging/another environment, and make your changes there.

Find some load testing tools to help mimic your high traffic scenarios. Perhaps it's as simple as capturing the traffic, and replaying against your copy. Depending on your database platform, you may have tools supplied.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that there was tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

Performance testing allows testers to judge how well an application or website performs under specific circumstances. Measuring the time taken, the scalability and reliability of an action is key to performance testing.Testing Anywhere allows testers to better create, manage, edit and analyze their performance tests.

Comment: your answer seems like you are a business consultant instead of an expert